# Python to drive Emacs; pymacs doesn't work

Tags: python, emacs, pymacs

I've got a python script that loops indefinitely waiting for input, and then 
does something when the input happens. My problem is then making python
tell emacs to do something. I just need some way to send emacs input
and make emacs evaluate that input.

Here's some code to illustrate my problem...

```
while(1):

  on_off = query_lightswitch
  if on_off == 0:
      send_text_to_emacs("(setq 'lightswitch t)")
```

Ideally I'd send emacs a string that it evaluates in its elisp interpreter.
I've tried pymacs, but it looks like pymacs is made to start stuff from
emacs rather than python. When I try something like this in pymacs
it locks up until the loop terminates. This looks like a problem I could
solve with unix pipelines, if I knew enough. 
If anybody out there has any ideas on how to solve this problem I'd
be much obliged, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [gnuclient](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnuClient) (shipped with Emacs 22) (or [emacsclient](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsClient) for earlier Emacsen), to evaluate code from external programs and connect to a running Emacs.

Getting Emacs to evaluate code by itself would look something like this:

```
gnuclient -q -batch -eval "(setq 'lightswitch t)"
```

Comment: gnuclient is an xemacs thing; GNU emacs always calls it emacsclient